# Best practice and solution to migrating BizTalk 2006 application to BizTalk 2016 environment?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

Is there any hidden tool from MS we can use for BizTalk application migration prior to load  solution into VS2015 ? I need some information about what are characteristic we may need to change specially BizTalk.btproj solution to load all project file etc., wonder to know easy approach migrating BizTalk application solution if any.

Comment: I managed to find the down load link for the Developer edition for 2010, so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As various [blogs posts](https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2015/12/migration-from-biztalk-2006-to-2013r2-lessons-learned/) and [MSDN threads](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9ac6b6c-3dbe-487b-85c5-448d257d62f4/migration-from-biztalk-server-2006-to-2013?forum=biztalkgeneral) you needed to have an intermediate Development BizTalk environment (BizTalk 2010) and then upgrading it to the later version like BizTalk 2013/R2 and up.

You can download the developer edition [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=24433) and install the SDK so you can open it in Visual Studio.

The only other way to migrate is to create new BizTalk Projects in Visual Studio 2015 / BizTalk 2016 environment, and then copying the artefacts such as Schemas, maps and re-creating any Orchestrations.

In either case you will have to do extensive retesting as there are certain changes such as the [XSLT compiled transform](https://danrosanova.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/the-biggest-change-in-biztalk-2013-and-how-to-undo-it/) that may cause you issues

Answer (score 1):

**No need for a hidden tool.  Visual Studio is the tool.**

When you open a downlevel Solution, Visual Studio will attempt to update any project and provide a report of what was automatically updated and what could not be updated, requiring manual intervention.

You can do this on a copy of you Solution to get a preview of any work necessary for the real upgrade.

Coming from BizTalk Server 2006, you will need an intermediate version to eventually target BizTalk Server 2016.  You can download BizTalk Server 2010 from MSDN.  All you need to install is the SDK.  You don't need to setup/configure full BizTalk Server.